# First Steps in Learning C++

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

I want to be a programmer; and I want to learn the basics of **C++**. Can anyone give me any pointers on how to start? I'm currently a complete novice and have no programming experience.

Comment: This is going to be controversial, but: Don't start with C++ (at least not if you don't have a teacher/mentor). It's so easy to adapt bad habits when following random online tutorials for C++ (the usual C++ questions on stackoverflow give a short overview of this...).

Comment: Check some stuff on YouTube.  For someone learning from the very beginning I suggest looking for and learning about Object Oriented Programming, learn Data Structures first.  As you learn through Data Structures you should be learning a decent bit about C++.

Comment: I'd go with 'Programming Principals and Practice using C++' from that book list.

Comment: Try to learn c first.IMHO

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of tutorials available online. Just search for tutorial and C++. Here is one for instance:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson1.html

An alternative would be to invest in a book!